# Powerquery list column names of all blank / null columns on each row

Tags: null, find, range, powerquery

Pls guide me to extract null cells if available from selected columns. this will help me to find null cell available in cell of selected columns... i have tried to get this data by if function but there are so many conditions needs to be put in if function. i need to this information by reducing the formula conditions if it is possible to get then pls support me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add a column that shows all the names of columns in that row that are null.  Is that what you are looking for?

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
Text.Combine(
    List.Transform(
        List.PositionOf(
            Record.ToList(_)
        ,null,999)
    , each Table.ColumnNames(Source){_}),
 ", ")
)
in #"Added Custom"
```

or more compactly

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.PositionOf(Record.ToList(_),null,999), each Table.ColumnNames(Source){_}),", "))
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: @horseyride- it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery use the **Filter** dropdown in the column header and either

- Remove Empty
- Unselect null

[image]

You could also **Replace values**, if this is what you want:

[image]

Comment: @Peter- I want "null available" information in column 10 with Columns headings... if multiple columns....

Comment: I want to track which field is not updated by users so i can inform them this field is pending to update.... Pls check below if formula for understanding what is requirement

if [#"BFDF/Regular"] = "BFDF" and [Billing Type] <> "ZY60" then "STO BFDF" else if [Transporter Name] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Number"] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Date"] = null and [#"Distance (KM)"] = null and [Vehical Number] = null and [Vehicle Type] = null and [EWB Number]= null and [Truck Capacity] = null then "Pending All Updation"

Comment: Continue 
else if [Transporter Name] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Number"] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Date"] = null and [#"Distance (KM)"] = null and [Vehical Number] = null and [Vehicle Type] = null and [EWB Number] = null then "Pending Transport Name, LR, Date, KM, Vehicle#, Type, EWB Updation" else if [Transporter Name] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Number"] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Date"] = null and [#"Distance (KM)"] = null and [Vehical Number] = null and [Vehicle Type] = null then "Pending Transport Name, LR, Date, KM, Vehicle#, Type

Comment: Updation" else if [Transporter Name] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Number"] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Date"] = null and [#"Distance (KM)"] = null and [Vehical Number] = null then "Pending Transport Name, LR, Date, KM, Vehicle# Updation" else if [Transporter Name] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Number"] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Date"] = null and [#"Distance (KM)"] = null then "Pending Transport Name, LR, Date, KM Updation"

Comment: else if [Transporter Name] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Number"] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Date"] = null then "Pending Transport Name, LR, Date, Updation" else if [Transporter Name] = null and [#"Transporter (LR) Document Number"] = null then "Pending Transport Name, LR, Updation" else if [Transporter Name] = null then "Pending Trans. Name" else if [#"Transporter (LR) Document Number"] = null then "Pending LR"

Comment: else if [#"Transporter (LR) Document Date"] = null then "Pending LR Date" else if [#"Distance (KM)"] = null then "Pending D. in KM" else if [Vehical Number] = null then "Pending Veh. Number"  else if [Vehicle Type] = null then "Pending Type" else if [EWB Number] = null then "Pending EWB#" else "Already Updated all Data"